# Which items in TF2 allow for self-healing?

Tags: team-fortress-2

What items/weapons in TF2 allow for self-healing or health regeneration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below are all the items classes can use to self-heal. Every single class has some sort of self-healing.

## **[Scout](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scout)**

- [Mad Milk](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Mad_Milk)

  - returns 60% of damage done to soaked enemies as healing for self and allies
- [Candy Cane](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Candy_Cane)

  - If the scout kills an enemy (even without the Candy Cane, as long as the Candy Cane is equipped) the enemy's body drops a small health kit

## **[Soldier](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Soldier)**

- [Concheror](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Concheror)

  - on use, returns 35% of damage done as healing for self and allies within a radius
- [Black Box](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Black_Box)

  - each successful hit yields +15 hp per enemy hit
- [Half-Zatoichi](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Half-Zatoichi)

  - upon kill, heals 50% of the killed enemy's max hp (and can overheal).
    (Note that if holstered/switched away without a kill, 50 health will be deducted from the player's current health. If the player is below 50 health points, the weapon can not be holstered until the player gets a kill or they get more health).

## **[Pyro](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Pyro)**

- [Phlogstinator](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Phlogistinator)

  - upon full "Mmph!", taunting grants full hp, damage resistance, and guaranteed critical hits
- [Powerjack](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Powerjack)

  - restores +75 hp with kill

## **[Demoman](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Demoman)**

- [Persian Persuader](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Persian_Persuader)

  - any ammo picked up from boxes or weapons is converted into health
  - dispensers provide no ammo, but resupply cabinets still do
- [Eyelander](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Eyelander)/[Nessie's Nine Iron](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Nessie%27s_Nine_Iron)/[Horseless Headless Horsemann's Headtaker](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Horseless_Headless_Horsemann%27s_Headtaker)

  - each successful kill increases speed by 8%, max hp by 15, and heals for 15
- [Half-Zatoichi](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Half-Zatoichi)

  - upon kill, heals 50% of the killed enemy's max hp (and can overheal).
    (Note that if holstered/switched away without a kill, 50 health will be deducted from the player's current health. If the player is below 50 health points, the weapon can not be holstered until the player gets a kill or they get more health).

## **[Heavy](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Heavy)**

- [Sandvich](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Sandvich)

  - heals +300 hp over 4 seconds.
- [Dalokohs Bar](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Dalokohs_Bar)/[Fishcake](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Fishcake)

  - heals and increases max hp by 50 for 30 seconds

## **[Engineer](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Engineer)**

- [Dispensers](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Dispenser)

  - Level 1: +10 hp per second
  - Level 2: +15 hp per second
  - Level 3: +20 hp per second

## **[Medic](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Medic)**

- Automatically heals +3 hp per second
- [Blutsauger](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Blutsauger)

  - heals +3 hp every successful hit, but drains -2 hp per second
- [Kritzkrieg](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Kritzkrieg)

  - [Oktoberfest taunt](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Oktoberfest) heals self +11 hp
- [Quick Fix](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Quick_Fix)

  - while using ÜberCharge, heals patient and medic +100.8 hp per second or +302.4 hp per second if out of combat
- [Amputator](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Amputator)

  - while [taunting](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Medicating_Melody), heals all allies at +25 hp per second (or +75 hp per second if out of combat) within a certain radius for 4.2 seconds

## **[Sniper](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Sniper)**

- [The Cozy Camper](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Cozy_Camper)

  - heals +2 hp per 2 seconds

## **[Spy](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Spy)**

- [Conniver's Kunai](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Conniver%27s_Kunai)

  - upon backstab, steals all hp from enemy

## **Misc**

- [Payload Objectives](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Payload#Carts) (Carts)

  - heals +10 hp per second
- [Resupply Locker](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Respawn#Resupply)

  - instant full heal
- [Health kits](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Health#Sources)

  - small: heals 20.5% of max hp
  - medium: heals 50% of max hp
  - large: heals 100% of max hp

Comment: The Amputator taunt does not heal yourself.